# Recursive function to destroy general tree c++

Tags: c++, recursion, tree

This is what I have so far for my DestroyTree function that gets call in the SkillTree desctructor:

```
void SkillTree::DestroyTree(Node*& root)
{

  if(root)
  {
      for(int i = 0; i < child_max && root && root->child[i]; ++i)
      {
          if(root)
          {
              DestroyTree(root->child[i]);
              delete root;
              root = NULL;
          }
      }

  }

}
```

I am slightly embarrassed for all the checks on root, but I was just trying to get it to work.

Also here is part my class definition if it is helpfull...

```
class SkillTree
{
  public:
    SkillTree(void);
    ~SkillTree(void);   

  protected:
    struct Node
    {
       Node() : max(DEFAULT_CHILD_MAX), child(new Node*[DEFAULT_CHILD_MAX])
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < max; ++i)
                child[i] = NULL;
        }

       ~Node()
       {
           for(int i = 0; i < max; ++i)
               delete child[i];

           child = NULL;
       }

       int max;
       Skill data;
       Node** child;    //a dynamic array of child pointers
    };

    void DestroyTree(Node*& root);

    int child_max;
    const static int DEFAULT_CHILD_MAX = 3;
    char* title;
    Node* root;
};
```

I don'e think the left most node is getting deleted along with other children besides the first of three. I know I have a memory leak, so I am hoping that if I get this fixed then my memory leak problem will be fixed as well.

Comment: In the future, whenever you need a "dynamic array" of something, please think [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of pointers.

Comment: I would also avoid array of pointers and instead use array of structures. It is cache friendly and avoids horrible pointer jumps.

Answer (score 1):

The DestroyTree function should look like this:

```
void SkillTree::DestroyTree()
{
    if (root)
    {
        delete root;
        root = NULL;
    }
}
```

and the Node destructor like this:

```
Node::~Node()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < max; ++i)
    {
        if (child[i])
            delete child[i];
    }
    delete [] child;
}
```

It's a bit long to list the reason for every change. If anything is unclear, feel free to ask!

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in that no matter how many children the root node have, it will only iterate (and recurse) *once*.

The reason? You delete and reset the `root` pointer inside the loop, and have the `root` pointer being a condition for the loop.

You should only have the initial check for `root` being non-null, and then delete/reset it *after* the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `delete[] child;` in Node's desctructor rather than deleting individual children. This is because `child` was constructed with `new[]`. Not doing so results in undefined behaviour.